# Why is the User Name missing in the flair?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, flair, display-names

On Area 51 for the [Programmers website](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3352/not-programming-related)

The User Name is missing for a user

Anyone knows why?
[image]

Is it a bug?

*Edit*
I found it on Opera 11.01 (Windows XP)

On IE 6 *(I know IE6 has CSS problems)*

But the flair is still the same

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couldn't repro at Chrome 11 and Firefox 3.6 for me.

[image]

But repro at Opera 11 (Linux version)

[image]

---

For opera, It looks like font-size is does not fit in the box, so shrinking the fontsize looks ok.

```
javascript:(function(){$(".userInfo").css("font-size","80%")})()
```

[image]

---

Sites other than area51 looks like using image based flair, so just switching flair to image based should fix the font size issue at area51.

[image: enter link description here]

**EDIT**: We took S.Mark's suggestion and switched to png flair on the beta pages, so these glitches are resolved now. -[Emmett](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/144066/emmett)